# Is there a way to detect if Outlook message does NOT have an attachment?

Tags: outlook

Ive been looking for a solution to this for a while now and need a bit of help.

I need to detect when someone sends me a message to my outlook account when it does not have attachents.

I have a situation that.

An email is sent to me
There is spacific text in the subject
It has an attachment
If it has an attachment it sends reply 1 and moves the message to folder A
If it does not have an attachmnet it sends reply 2.and moves the message into folder B

Any help would be welcome

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do this very easily in VBScript, like so:

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
Dim m As Variant
Dim strBody As String
Dim intIn As Long
Dim intAttachCount As Integer, intStandardAttachCount As Integer

On Error GoTo handleError

'Edit the following line if you have a signature on your email that includes images or other files. Make intStandardAttachCount equal the number of files in your signature.
intStandardAttachCount = 0

strBody = LCase(Item.Body)

intIn = InStr(1, strBody, "original message")

If intIn = 0 Then intIn = Len(strBody)

intIn = InStr(1, Left(strBody, intIn), "attach")

intAttachCount = Item.Attachments.Count

If intIn > 0 And intAttachCount <= intStandardAttachCount Then

    m = MsgBox("It appears that you mean to send an attachment," & vbCrLf & "but there is no attachment to this message." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Do you still want to send?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo + vbMsgBoxSetForeground)

    If m = vbNo Then Cancel = True

End If

handleError:

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    MsgBox "Outlook Attachment Reminder Error: " & Err.Description, vbExclamation, "Outlook Attachment Reminder Error"
End If

End Sub
```

This can be modified for your exact need, but it's pretty straightforward.

Simple Google search away. Give [credit](https://sites.google.com/site/markbird/) to the guy who wrote it.